# Why is JavaScript V8 Engine called an Engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I am taking a course on Udemy and in one of the lessons the instructor says that the JavaScript V8 Engine is written in C++ and it translates your javascript to machine language. Why wouldn't we just call it a translator? what does an engine have to do with it? I'm sorry if this may be a stupid question but I'm just curious. Thanks!

Comment: How would you describe the "translation" that you have in your mind?

Comment: It doesn't just translate, it executes your code. There are many definitions for [engine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engine).

Comment: It doesn't translate to machine language.  It parses the code into an abstract syntax tree, and executes it against a "Virtual Machine".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terminology.

Comment: How would you define the English word "engine"? I might say something like "An engine is a machine that performs some kind of work, usually converting one type of energy into another (e.g., turning electrical energy into mechanical energy)." - So, metaphorically, that's what the JS engine does: it takes your code and processes it to produce some output. And of course once you start thinking in terms of engines, "V8" implies power and speed.

Comment: V8 is also a well known mechanical engine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_engine The reference seems obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because it sounds cooler and is easier to talk about to a layman audience.

> A **JavaScript engine** is a virtual machine which interprets and executes
>   JavaScript (in the traditional lingo of programming languages, it
>   should thus be called a **JavaScript interpreter**).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine